# Error message: "undefined reference to `print", don't know what it is?

Tags: reference, undefined

```
# include <stdio.h>

    main()
    {

          int name, age, siblings, children;

          printf ("Hello my name is A.I, what is your name?\n");
          scanf("%d", &name);
          print ("Hello", name,"How old are you?\n");
          scanf("%d", &age);
          printf("Do you have any brothers and sisters?\n");
          scanf("%d", &siblings);
          printf("and how many children do you have?\n");
          scanf("%d", &children);
          printf("So your name is\n", name, "you are", age, "you have", siblings, "brothers/sisters and have", children, "children\n");
          getchar();

    }
```

**This is my first program, i apologise if my mistake is very simple but i have not been able to figure out what i'm doing wrong??**

Comment: `print ("Hello", name ,"How old are you?\n");` should be `printf ("Hello", name ,"How old are you?\n");`

Comment: Oh thanks i didn't notice that.

Answer (score 4):

The printing function in `stdio.h` is `printf`!

Comment: he means the same thing I said?  I just posted an example of what he meant in your comment